# Applying function cumulative to every elements from list of any type

Tags: java, algorithm

I have list of objects like `List<T>` where `T` may be of any type. I need function which return object of type `T` - it will be result of applying `Function<T,T,T>` cumulative to every object from `List<T>`.

Example:

For `List<Integer> integers = [3,1,9]` and `Function<Integer, Integer> = (a,b) -> a+b` as result I should receive `13`. But for function `Function<Integer, Integer> = (a,b) -> a*b` result will be `27`.

Comment: That's exactly what reduction does on a stream.

Comment: Doing the same with a simple loop shouldn't be hard either if Streams are too advanced for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the Stream.reduce function: given a list and a binary operator:

```
List<Integer> integers = List.of(3, 1, 9);
BinaryOperator<Integer> add = (a,b)  -> a + b;
BinaryOperator<Integer> multiply = (a,b) -> a * b;
```

The reduce function applies the binary operator to each item in the list  and the result from the previous step:

```
Integer sum = integers.stream().reduce(0, add); // = 0+3+1+9 = 13
Integer product = integers.stream().reduce(1, multiply); // = 1*3*1*9 = 27
```

There is also a variant that doesn't require an initial element, but it returns `Optional` to handle the case when the list is empty.

```
Optional<Integer> sum = integers.stream().reduce(add);
Optional<Integer> product = integers.stream().reduce(multiply);
```

More information:

- [API reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-)
- [Java tutorial on streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html#reduce)
- [Baeldung: Guide to `Stream.reduce()`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-reduce)